# Rabbitmq with nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using nginx controller with Minikube. I can access rabbitmq management but when i access the queues i got this error:

[Not found
The object you clicked on was not found; it may have been deleted on the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzYIG.png)

if i use port-forward it's working correctly

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:
    name: rabbitmq-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /rabbit(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: rabbitmq-management
                port:
                  number: 15672
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget to mention **host** into ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```

host: "foo.bar.com"

Read more : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards